# Set time zone using Clock Configuration Service Provider

Tags: windows-mobile, timezone

I am attempting to use the Clock CSP to set the system time zone on a Windows Mobile 6 Professional device (Opticon H-19A).

I am using the following XML:

```
<characteristic type="clock">
  <parm name="TimeZone" value="35" />
<characteristic>
```

DMProcessConfigXML is returning E_FAIL and the XML output string matches the XML input string.

Does anyone know why this isn't working?  Is there a better (reliable) way to set the time zone for Windows Mobile 5/6 & Pocket PC 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use the GetTimeZoneInformation/SetTimeZoneInformation API to adjust the time zone.